# Add dynamically iframe with html content in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, iframe

My requirement is to add iframe at runtime and insert an external 3rd party widget having script that send request to 3rd party server to add widget and insert in our html.
So I have one li tag in which I want to dynamically insert iframe with 3rd party widget

Comment: which iframe is this? Can  you post some snippets ? Just to illustrate?

Comment: What is the question? `My requirement` isn't a code related  problem description. When updating question with particulars also show your attempts/research to resolve your requirement

Comment: <li> <iframe> some script of 3rd party by which html data will come </iframe></li>

Answer (score 0):

You can add your iframe to the page and use ng-src to set the iframes source.

```
<iframe ng-src="{{contentUrl}}"></iframe>
```

You can then dynamically set the content url by updating contentUrl in the $scope of your app

```
$scope.contentUrl = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```